# Why is C telling me I need a pointer to a function for my MSP430

Tags: c

I am using the following code:

```
#include <msp430.h>

int flip(int flip){
    if (flip) {flip = 0;}
    else {flip = 1;}
    return flip;
}

/*...*/

void main(void){
    int ctrl = 0;
    while(1){
        ctrl = flip(ctrl);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to compile I get the error, referring to the line:

```
ctrl = flip(ctrl);

error #110: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

I don't understand why the compiler is giving me this error.

Replies are correct: the compiler doesn't like it when I'm using the same name for a variable and a function. Fixed.

Comment: you have `flip` declared both as a function and as an `int`.

Comment: What is your platform? What is your compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is getting confused because, in your context, `flip` refers both to a function and to an `int`.  You should change the name of the argument to something else.

Comment: OTOH most compilers accept this code. The form of the error message suggests the OP must use some pretty old/weird compiler.